# Is it possible to detect the "composer mode" from witin layer expression

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression

I was wondering if I could create an expression for a layer style that can "detect" the "composer mode" so that it can behave differently when the map is printed (like label priority handling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - the @map_id expression variable will be either set to the name of the composer map item in which the rendering is occuring or "canvas" if the rendering is occurring inside the main map canvas.

So you can write an expression like

```
case when @map_id='canvas' then 5 else 1 end
```

Comment: nice ! I will give it a try and check the answer !